# Android: Implementar LIbreria Glide

Tags: android

Intente implementar una librería ***Universal Image Loader*** pero la verdad no entiendí nada de la documentación entonces busque otras, ahora busco adaptar mi forma en la que yo mostraba mis imagenes pero utilizando [GLIDE](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), lo que pasa es que quiero mostrar las imagenes en IndexActivity (es mi actividad donde tengo inicializado mi GridView) pero que se vean como cargan porque antes lo que hacia era lanzar el **IndexActivity** hasta que no estuvieran todas la imagenes, pero eso me esta perjudicando para otros procesos que quiero hacer.

> IndexActivity.java

```
//creo una instancia de CheckIn
 CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();
 ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
 if (checkIn.getImages().size() > 0) {//valido de que existan imagenes
    for (ImageData object: checkIn.getImages()) {
        bitmaps.add(object.getBitmap());//al ArrayList le agrego los Bitmaps
    }//for
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, bitmaps));//seteo las imagenes al gridView
}//./if
```

> PictureActivity.java

```
  CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();//TODO YA NO
  for (int i = 0; i < principalListOfImages.size(); i++) {
      ImageData imageData = new ImageData();//creo una instancia de ImageData
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(principalListOfImages.get(i));//paso el path a Bitmap
      imageData.setBitmap(bitmap);//le setteo el bitmap
      imageData.setPath(principalListOfImages.get(i));//le setteo el path
      checkIn.getImages().add(imageData);//recupero mi arreglo de objetos y le setteo mi nuevo objeto
      listOfBitmaps.add(bitmap);//cada BItmap lo setteo al arraylist
  }//for

   new UploadImage().execute(listOfBitmaps);
```

> UploadImage.java (AsyncTask)

```
 //ejecuta nuestras tareas  
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {principales
     CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
     CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse;

 try {

    CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();//hago una instancia de checkin
    JSONObject jsonImage = new JSONObject();//creo un JSONObject

    ArrayList<Bitmap> listOfBitmaps = (ArrayList<Bitmap>) params[0];//Obtengo mi Arreglo de objetos para despues pasarlos a un array lis de Bitmap
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();//permitira la salida de los bytes

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfBitmaps.size(); i++) {//itero el arreglo

        listOfBitmaps.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream);//se comprime la imagen
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();//codifica el path a un arreglo de byte
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);//codifico ese byteArray a base64 y despues a scrintg

        jsonImage.put("folio", checkIn.getFolio());//paso el folio al JSONObject
        jsonImage.put("images", encoded);//le paso al JSONObject los codigos de las iameges

        StringEntityHC4 entityHC4 = new StringEntityHC4(jsonImage.toString(), ContentType.create("json/application", "UTF-8"));//la direccion del servidor a la que va a apuntar
        HttpPutHC4 httpPutHC4 = new HttpPutHC4(DynamicUrl.BASE_URL + DynamicUrl.SERVER_HOST + ":" + DynamicUrl.SERVER_PORT + "/api/checkkin");//la direccion del dervidor al que va a apuntar

        httpPutHC4.setEntity(entityHC4);//seteo los datos que tengo en el JSONObject

        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();//La configuracion del servidor va a ser default
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPutHC4);//Obtengo la respuesta del servidor

        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {//si el estatus de la respuesta es igual a 200
            JSONObject jsonRosponse = new JSONObject(EntityUtilsHC4.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));//creo un JSONObject y le paso el JSON que recibio de la sespuesta del servidor

            if (jsonRosponse.getString("code").equals("OK")) {//checo que el JSON tenga la clave OK
                System.out.println("Las imagenes se guardaron correctamente");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error al subir las imagenes");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un error");
        }
    }//./for
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Nunca lo he implementado, pero estos apuntes los estuve leyendo hace unos días y me parecieron interesantes. Te los dejo: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: @javier en IndexActivity pero que elemento? agregaré la forma de mostrarlo en los elementos, en este caso no necesitas obtener el bitmap, simplemente el url, Glide administra el cache y la memoria necesaria.

Comment: Hola Elenasys, si ya lo cambie ahora ya le mando un Array de String

Comment: que es donde mando mi url ya le estoy entendiendo un poco mas a Glide pero aun le estoy batallando para mostrar las imagenes

Comment: Estoy modificando mi ImageAdapter.java

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas realizando la construcción de un proyecto por las preguntas que has realizado, en cuanto a la carga de las imágenes mediante [Glide](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2014/09/glide-30-media-management-library-for.html), no necesitas tener las imágenes como mapa de bits, lo que se realiza generalmente es cargar las imágenes desde recursos o desde una url.

```
//Obtienes la referencia del ImageView en donde se cagaría la imagen.
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

//Indicas a Glide que imagen cargar y en que vista.
Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://www.midominio.com/myimagen.jpg")
    .into(imageView);
```

Lo interesante de [Glide](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2014/09/glide-30-media-management-library-for.html) es que administra el cache y la memoria requerida para procesar la imagen de una forma optima, además de que es mucho más sencilla su implementación con respecto a `Universal Image Loader`.

---

Reconsidera usar un `ArrayList` de urls de imágenes para cargar estas imágenes mediante [Glide](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2014/09/glide-30-media-management-library-for.html) ,

```
ArrayList<String> urlBitmaps = new ArrayList<String>();
```

en lugar de lo que tienes actualmente :

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

Comment: Elenasys ya estoy en la implementacion pero me genero errores puedes checar mi nueva publicacion

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40597/android-problemas-al-implementar-glide-con-gridview

Comment: Perfecto!!!!!  veo que realizaste el cambio actualmente! =)! a un ArrayList que contiene los url de imagenes, excelente.