# Problemas al implementar Glide con GridView en Android

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al implementar Glide en mi GridView, me base en esta pagina [Glide](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-listadapter-listview-gridview)

> activity_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:title="Bienvenido">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/data_checkin" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_picture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:src="@drawable/picture"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:backgroundTint="#fff"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab_home"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:backgroundTint="#fff"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeScot"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="300dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

> IndexActivity.java

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (checkIn.getImages().size() > 0) {//valido de que existan imagenes
        for (ImageData object: checkIn.getImages()) {
            strings.add(object.getPath());//al ArrayList le agrego los Bitmaps
        }//for
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, strings));//seteo las imagenes al gridView
    }//./if
```

> ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> imagesList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imagesList){
    super(context, R.layout.activity_index, imagesList);//recibe como parametros el Contexto y un ArrayList de Bitmaps
    this.mContext = context;//se asgina valores
    this.imagesList = imagesList;//se asgina valores
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}//./constructor

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_index, parent, false);
    }

    Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into((ImageView) convertView);

    return convertView;
}

}//./clase
```

me esta marcando el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.tritonix.scotproyect, PID: 4923
              java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
                  at com.example.tritonix.scotproyect.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:65)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2828)
                  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1064)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18648)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18648)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1420)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                  at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:482)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18648)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:703)
                  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:768)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18648)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18648)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18648)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3012)
                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18648)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2298)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1345)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1644)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6748)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Falta obtener la referencia del ImageView, en tu layout cual es el imageView donde agregarías la imagen =P ? @Javierfr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta la referencia del `ImageView` en donde agregaras la imagen, de hecho no esta contenida en el layout `activity_index.xml`:

```
  Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(ImageView);
```

Tienes que obtener la referencia del contenedor `ImageView` en donde sería cargada la imagen, por ejemplo:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

 Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(myImageView);
```

---

Ejemplo implementando la carga de la imagen dentro de `getView()` :

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
if (imagesList.size() > 0) { imageView.setImageBitmap(imagesList.get(position)); } 
//caracteristicas del ImageView imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150)); 
Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(imageView);
return imageView; 
}
```

Comment: si me falta pero no se como hacerle, lo que pasa es que anteriormete tenia mi ImageView en mi mismo ImageAdapter.java

Comment: como esto@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        if (imagesList.size() > 0) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imagesList.get(position));
        }
        //caracteristicas del ImageView
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));

        return imageView;
    }

Comment: Dentro de getView() es buena idea, pero porque lo quitaste?

Comment: Elenasys voy bien con mi codigo?

Comment: Porque no se como ponerlo a Glide.with...

Comment: Primeramente donde esta el ImageView donde deseas cargar la imagen? No lo veo en el layout

Comment: No tengo ningun ImageView en mi XML anteriormente tenia otro codigo pero le e hido modificando antes en el gridView lo tenia asi

Comment: ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

Comment: ahi mismo lo cree

Comment: NO entiendo donde debo crear mi ImageView

Comment: prueba la actualización de getView()

Comment: si deja checo tu nuevo codigo

Comment: pero porque un setImageBitmap si ahora lo que tengo en miarreglo es la URL (String)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50561/discussion-between-javier-fr-and-elenasys).

Answer (score 3):

bueno te muestro mi metodo para usar `Glide` y `Gridview`. primero creo una clase llamada `Foto` donde caragara un nombre y la respectiva imagen(local)

```
public class Foto {
private String nombre;
private int idDrawable;

public Foto(String nombre, int idDrawable) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.idDrawable = idDrawable;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public int getIdDrawable() {
    return idDrawable;
}

public int getId() {
    return nombre.hashCode();
}

public static Foto[] ITEMS = {
        new Foto("Ejemplo 1", R.drawable.sts),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 2", R.drawable.imagen),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 3", R.drawable.auditorio1),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 4", R.drawable.auditorio2),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 5", R.drawable.auditorio3),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 6", R.drawable.auditorio4),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 7",R.mipmap.st),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 8", R.mipmap.st),
        new Foto ("Ejemplo 9", R.mipmap.st),
        new Foto("Ejemplo 10", R.mipmap.st),
};

/**
 * Obtiene item basado en su identificador
 *
 * @param id identificador
 * 
 */
public static Foto getItem(int id) {
    for (Foto item : ITEMS) {
        if (item.getId() == id) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Luego creo una clase llamada `AdaptadorDeFotos` esta implementa `Glide`para cargar las fotos

```
public class AdaptadorDeFotos extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public AdaptadorDeFotos(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Foto.ITEMS.length;
}

@Override
public Foto getItem(int position) {
    return Foto.ITEMS[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    ImageView imagenCoche = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagen_coche);
    TextView nombreCoche = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_coche);
    final Foto item = getItem(position);
    Glide.with(imagenCoche.getContext())
            .load(item.getIdDrawable())
            .into(imagenCoche);

    nombreCoche.setText(item.getNombre());

    return view;
}
```

}

y luego en la clase principal

```
public class AdaptadorDeFotos extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public AdaptadorDeFotos(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Foto.ITEMS.length;
}

@Override
public Foto getItem(int position) {
    return Foto.ITEMS[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    ImageView imagenCoche = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagen_coche);
    TextView nombreCoche = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_coche);
    final Foto item = getItem(position);
    Glide.with(imagenCoche.getContext())
            .load(item.getIdDrawable())
            .into(imagenCoche);

    nombreCoche.setText(item.getNombre());

    return view;
}
```

}

y para cuando el usuario haga click sobre la imagen esta se abra en un activity nuevo

```
public class ActividadPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

{
    private GridView gridView;
    private AdaptadorDeFotos adaptador;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_principal);


    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    adaptador = new AdaptadorDeFotos(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adaptador);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}


    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id){
    Foto item = (Foto) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActividadDetalle.class);
    intent.putExtra(ActividadDetalle.EXTRA_PARAM_ID, item.getId());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptions =
                ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                        this,
                        new Pair<View, String>(view.findViewById(R.id.imagen_coche),
                                ActividadDetalle.VIEW_NAME_HEADER_IMAGE)
                );

        ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, activityOptions.toBundle());
    } else
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

actividad principal XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
```

y el layout al hacer click en la imagen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_actividad_detalle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.hp14.iteracion2.Galeria.ActividadDetalle"
android:background="@color/black_overlay">

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imagen_extendida"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

</ImageView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar3" />
```

Espero te ayude en algo, saludos !